# How to constrain duplicate removal for specific data.frame in the list more elegantly?

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I have data.frame objects in the list as an output of custom function, and I intend to proceed duplicate removal only first data.frame objects, while others shouldn't not be effected. I tried this in lapply function to control this constrain, but I have subscript error instead. I know this easier to do it in separately, but this is not desired for me. Can anyone point me out how to make this easier in functional programming ? Does anyone knows any useful trick of controlling the constrain on specific objects in the list ?

mini example:

```
myList <- list(
  bar = data.frame(v1=c(12,21,37,21,37), v2=c(14,29,45,29,45)),
  cat = data.frame(v1=c(18,42,18,42,81), v2=c(27,46,27,46,114)),
  foo = data.frame(v1=c(3,3,33,3,33,91), v2=c(26,26,42,26,42,107))
)
```

it is easy to do like this:

```
.first <- unique(myList[[1L]])
res <- c(list(.first), myList[- 1L])
```

but I need to constrain duplicate removal only effect on the first data.frame, while others doesn't do remove duplicate, I intend to implement this in function more elegant way.

desired output:

```
myOutput <- list(
  bar = data.frame(v1=c(12,21,37),v2=c(14,29,45)),
  cat = data.frame(v1=c(18,42,18,42,81), v2=c(27,46,27,46,114)),
  foo = data.frame(v1=c(3,3,33,3,33,91), v2=c(26,26,42,26,42,107))
)
```

Comment: Why can't you update `myList[[1]] <- unique(myList[[1]])` or loop through the sequence `lapply(seq_along(myList), function(i) if(i==1) unique(myList[[i]]) else myList[[i]])`

Comment: Updated my comment

Comment: Thanks, update this as an answer, upvote your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we need to use `lapply`, then we can loop through the sequence of `list`, and with `if/else` modify the `list` elements

```
lapply(seq_along(myList), function(i) if(i==1) unique(myList[[i]]) else myList[[i]])
```

---

Or else we can assign the modified `list` element

```
myList[[1]] <- unique(myList[[1]])
```